# "Tensor Placeholder " error received while predicting as tensorflow savedModel with input type as string

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict

I have exported my keras model to tensorflow savedModel and uploaded it to cloud ML engine to serve predictions. When I send the json request (with input as float) it serves the predictions correctly. But when i send the json request (with base64 encoded string of the image) i get the error
 "Tensor Placeholder_107:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph"

```
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
K.set_learning_phase(0)
model = load_model('modelName.h5')

image = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)
export_path = 'path-name'

builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'image_bytes': image},
                              outputs={'scores': model.output})

with K.get_session() as sess:
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                     tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                     signature_def_map={
                                         'predict': signature})

builder.save()
```

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['predict']:

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):

```
      inputs['images'] tensor_info:
       dtype: DT_STRING
       shape: (-1)
       name: Placeholder_107:0
```

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):

```
   outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: activation_14/Softmax:0
```

Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

Have passed the image data to convert it to json file so that it can be sent to cloud ML engine for prediction

```
from base64 import b64encode
from json import dumps
import json

with open(IMAGE_NAME, 'rb') as open_file:
   byte_content = open_file.read()
base64_bytes = b64encode(byte_content)                      
raw_data = {IMAGE_NAME: base64_bytes}
request_body= json.dumps({'images': base64_bytes})
with open('test_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
 outfile.write(request_body)
```

Then I pass this json (base64 encode of the image) to cloud ML engine

```
  !gcloud ml-engine predict --model model-name --version version_3 --json-instances test_data.json
```

I get the below error

```
 ['{', '  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\\"Tensor Placeholder_107:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph\\")"', '}']
```

Earlier I sent the model input as float as below

```
  signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'image_bytes': image},
                              outputs={'scores': model.output})
```

at that time

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):

```
   inputs['images'] tensor_info:
     dtype: DT_FLOAT
     shape: (-1, 96, 96, 3)
     name: conv2d_6_input:0
```

I suspect the issue is due to this line . tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string).

Once I changed the signature def to accept tf.placeholder i am facing issue. I am using the tf.placeholder to make it accept input as string.

I tried many ways on seeing some inputs from SO solutions but it didn't help

Please advice

Comment: Did you solve the problem?